# Shell/Bash shortcut for bulk renaming of files in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, file-io, scripting

Is there a shortcut in Shell/Bash that can rename all the files in a folder based on a regex or some other criteria. What I am looking for here is in my folder documents, that has let's say a 100 text files with the following naming convention:

```
<longdocumentidentifier>-doc-<counter>.txt.
```

I need to rename all the files with the above given convention to just:

```
doc-<counter>.txt
```

Is there a one-liner that can help me with the above?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
for i in *-doc-*.txt; do mv "$i" "${i/*-doc-/doc-}"; done
```

`${i/*-doc-/doc-}` replaces the first occurrence of `*-doc-` with `doc-`.

If you need to do more than one replacement (see comment number 1), you need to use the `${var//Pattern/Replacement}` variant. If you need to replace the beginning of the name you need to use `${var/#Pattern/Replacement}`, if you need to replace the end (ie: the extension) you need to use the `${var/%Pattern/Replacement}` form.

See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion-1) for more details. This expansion is bash specific.

Comment: This was helpful for a slightly different case; where I wanted to replace all the spaces in some file names with dashes: `for i in *; do mv "$i" ${i//\ /-}; done`. Note that for this to work I had to quote the original file names.

Comment: I used it to remove .sh from all scripts names :-) `for i in *.sh; do mv $i ${i/.sh/}; done`.

Comment: @erm3nda be careful:`${i/.sh/}` deletes the first match of the .sh string. To make sure that you remove the extension (which I'm assuming you want) you should use `${i/%.sh/}`

Comment: Because `*` was used to match the element to be replaced by `i/` i didn't guess that `%` works like `$1` match group at regexp. Much better, thank you.

Comment: @erm3nda % has nothing to do with $1. `/%` means match the suffix of the string.

Comment: $1 is what you save with regex when you do `/(.*).sh/$1/`. I just comented how to compare both situations. I didn't expect that the parameter substitution does use other chars for it's work. Srry :-) and thanks.

Answer (score 28):

If you have `rename` then, `rename 's/^.*-doc-/doc-/' *.txt` should do the trick.

Answer (score 16):

There is `prename`, that allows you to use REGEX:

```
prename 's/^.*-doc-(.*\.txt)$/doc-$1/'  *.txt
```

Use the option `-n` to simulate:

```
prename -n 's/^.*-doc-(.*\.txt)$/doc-$1/'  *.txt
```

**Note:** This is the shipped as `rename` in many Linux distributions, but not in all of them -- so I'm using the canonical name for the utility that comes with Perl.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to recurse into sub-directories, there is also:

```
find . -maxdepth N -type f -name "$pattern" | sed -e 'p' -E -e "s/$str1/$str2/g" | xargs -n2 mv
```

On system that automatically support extended Regexps, you can leave away the `-E`.

Advantages:

- recurses into sub-directories
- you can control the maxdepth of the recursion
- you can rename files and/or directories (-type f|d)

Disadvantages:

- slightly more complicated regexps, because you have to strip out the path to get at the file name

(answer amended from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12606036/1334781))

Comment: I'm getting the following error when running this: `sed: -e expression #2, char 33: unterminated \`s' command`. Any advice?

Answer (score 8):

The rename command built in to most linux, eg, will do this easily.

Personally, I prefer regexps too which is why I've been carrying around this script for a very very very long time (read: since the late 80s or early 90s):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

($op = shift) || die "Usage: $0 expr [files]]\n";

if(!@ARGV)
  {
  @ARGV = <STDIN>;
  chop(@ARGV);
  }

for (@ARGV)
  {
  $was = $_;
  eval $op;
  die $@ if $@;

  if ($was ne $_)
    {
    print "rename($was,$_)\n";
    rename($was,$_);
    }
  }
```

Which, when installed lets you do things like this:

```
script-name 's/.*-doc(.*).txt/doc$1.txt/' *.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

```
mmv "*-doc-*" "doc-#2"
```

mmv command stands for "mass move"

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind external tool, then here's one: [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm) ([web page](http://neurobin.github.io/rnm/))

For your particular problem the command would be:

```
rnm -rs '/.*-doc-/doc-/' *.txt
```

Or

```
rnm -rs '/.*-(doc-.*\.txt)/\1/' *.txt
```

You can find more examples/docs [here](http://neurobin.github.io/Docs/Linux/rnm/bulk-rename-in-linux/).

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*scss' | xargs -L1 -I {} echo {} {} | sed 's/css\.scss$/scss/' | xargs -L1 mv
```

for example if you have a bunch of files ending with ".css.scss" and you want to rename them to end with simply ".scss" (ie remove the .css part)

tweak the regexp and find arguments to your needs