# Looking for a way to rename lots of files at once

Tags: regex, bash

For every file in the current directory, I'd like to:
Replace "-" with " - " and replace "+" with " ".

I'm guessing this will be some sort of combination of bash script and regular expressions, but I've never done either. I'm on OS X, though I don't think that should matter.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something by yourself?

Comment: Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416990/shell-bash-shortcut-for-bulk-renaming-of-files-in-a-folderlinux/8418112#8418112

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in *; do 
    new=${file//-/ - }; 
    new=${new//+/ }; 
    if [ "$file" != "$new" ]; then 
        mv "$file" "$new"; 
    fi; 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The unix way:

```
for a in * ; do 
    mv $a $(echo $a | sed -s 's/-/ - /' -e 's/\+/ /')
done
```

The unix debugging way involves running 'echo mv' before 'mv' until you're sure.

Comment: That's going to have problems because of the spaces in the names, enclose them in quotes.

Comment: Not just, "potential problems," but guaranteed problems, since it's adding spaces to the destination filename…

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I'd recommend to install/use [detox](http://linux.die.net/man/1/detox).

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin I would use tr to be on the safe side, also you need a second pipe operator between the sed commands:

```
for f in `ls` ; do 
    mv $f $(echo $f | sed -s 's/-/ - /' | tr '+' ' ')
done
```

If you want to suppress the error messages about moving same file onto itself use the following:

```
for f in `ls` ; do 
    n=$(echo $f | tr -s 's/-/ - /' | tr '+' ' ')
    if [ $f != $n ]; then
        mv $f $n
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
for FILE in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`; do mv "$FILE" "`echo "$FILE" | sed -e 's/-/ - /g' -e 's/+/ /g'`"; done;
```

Comment: It is a loop which loops over list of files in current directory (`find ...`) and for every file found it replaces '`-`' to '` - `' and '`+`' to '` `' using `sed` and regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
printf "%s\n" * | 
sed 'h;y/+/ /;s/-/ - /g;x;G;/\(.*\)\n\(\1\)/d;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/mv -v '\''\1'\'' '\''\2'\''/' |
sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, here is the Bash way to do it, but I don't know for sure if it will work in OSX. It uses the nifty trick of [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

```
for file in *
do
  newFile=${file//+/ }
  newFile=${newFile//-/ - }
  mv "$file" "$newFile"
done
```

**EDIT:** Okay, which one of y'all downvoted me? Explain yourself. My answer is nearly identical to the top one, and I answered first.

Comment: It wasn't me, but 1. you should check whether the file needs to be moved, and 2. you forgot the sigil (`$`) in front of `file` in the `mv`.