# Rename multiple directories with one domain name to another domain name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have many directories with some phrase (domain name) in its name. Need to change that phrase to another one (another domain name). How to do that simply ? Example below:

Before:

```
$ ls /var/www
drwxr-x--- 12 apache apache    4096 Dec 16 10:28 somewhere.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 apache apache    4096 Jan 28  2011 maven.somewhere.com
drwxr-x---  6 apache apache    4096 Feb 24  2010 mini.somewhere.com
drwxr-x---  3 apache apache    4096 Jul 16  2010 ml.somewhere.com
...
```

After

```
$ ls /var/www
drwxr-x--- 12 apache apache    4096 Dec 16 10:28 elsewhere.com
drwxr-xr-x  3 apache apache    4096 Jan 28  2011 maven.elsewhere.com
drwxr-x---  6 apache apache    4096 Feb 24  2010 mini.elsewhere.com
drwxr-x---  3 apache apache    4096 Jul 16  2010 ml.elsewhere.com
...
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Shell/Bash shortcut for bulk renaming of files in a folder(linux)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416990/shell-bash-shortcut-for-bulk-renaming-of-files-in-a-folderlinux)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$ cd /var/www
$ for i in *; do echo mv $i ${i/somewhere/elsewhere}; done
```

if the output looks ok:

```
$ for i in *; do echo mv $i ${i/somewhere/elsewhere}; done |sh
```

Comment: you should quote your variable expansions in case his dirs have spaces in their names

Comment: I don't get get the pipe to sh, isn't it simpler to remove the echo ?

Comment: @Sorin: not really, arrow-up + `|sh` + enter is faster than removing the `echo`. And this keeps the executed commands really close to what you see displayed on screen.

Comment: @SiegeX: if I'd do that, you'd be the first to point out the problems with filenames containing either `'` or `"`, won't you? ;-)

Comment: perfect. I would add `-v` to the final `mv`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `rename` that comes with perl.

```
$ rename 's/somewhere/elsewhere/' *
```