# Shell script to change file name using for loop

Tags: linux, shell

I want to change file names in a folder in a way like this:

```
previous form             new form
one-1      to           VAS-M0001-001
one-2      to           VAS-M0001-002
one-3      to           VAS-M0001-003
one-4      to           VAS-M0001-004
```

Can anyone please suggest me a good way to do that?

Comment: Please check whether http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416990/shell-bash-shortcut-for-bulk-renaming-of-files-in-a-folderlinux solves your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rename` has such a functionality

```
[username@hostname aa]$ touch one-1 one-2 one-3 one-4
[username@hostname aa]$ ls
one-1  one-2  one-3  one-4
[username@hostname aa]$ rename one- VAS-M0001-000 one*
[username@hostname aa]$ ls
VAS-M0001-0001  VAS-M0001-0002  VAS-M0001-0003  VAS-M0001-0004
```

Comment: syntax error at (user-supplied code) line 3, at EOF

Answer (score 3):

I would just use a simple loop:

```
for f in one-*; do mv one-$f VAS-M001-000$f; done
```

Of course, you can use printf to format the number better (if you have more than 9 files)