# Rename foldername to filename with bash

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I want to rename a file, by using the folder name.

This:

```
├── foo01
│   └── bar.png
│   └── bar.txt
├── foo02
│   └── bar.png
│   └── bar.txt
└── foo03
    └── bar.png
    └── bar.txt
```

Should be this:

```
├── foo01
│   └── foo01.png
│   └── foo01.txt
├── foo02
│   └── foo02.png
│   └── foo02.txt
└── foo03
    └── foo03.png
    └── foo03.txt
```

I can't find a way to do this. Can anybody help?

Comment: What did you tried so far? See this for bulk renaming: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416990/shell-bash-shortcut-for-bulk-renaming-of-files-in-a-folder

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Perl**‘s standalone rename command:

```
rename -n 's|([^/]*)/[^/]*\.(.*)$|$1/$1.$2|' */*
```

Output:

```
foo01/bar.png renamed as foo01/foo01.png
foo01/bar.txt renamed as foo01/foo01.txt
foo02/bar.png renamed as foo02/foo02.png
foo02/bar.txt renamed as foo02/foo02.txt
foo03/bar.png renamed as foo03/foo03.png
foo03/bar.txt renamed as foo03/foo03.txt
```

If everything looks okay, remove option `-n`.

Comment: I used `s|regex|string|` to transform elements of path and filename to a new string. The syntax is very similar to `sed`‘s `s` command.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I have to take rename (not prename) with the same syntax, and everything works fine. 200 files are renamed :)