# Unix Renaming Files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I want to rename files in a folder on UNIX using a script.
The format of the original file is:

`abc.txt.temp`

and I want to rename it to:

`abc.txt`

Many files use this format and I want to remove **.temp** from the original file name.

Comment: show `which prename` output

Comment: You might want to use the `mmv` tool: `mmv "*.txt.temp" "#1.txt"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell/Bash shortcut for bulk renaming of files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416990/shell-bash-shortcut-for-bulk-renaming-of-files-in-a-folder)

Comment: Not a duplicate because the question wants to substitute/remove part of a filename and not do a rename. Also, it isn't off-topic because it's clearly asking for a **bash script** to do this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer Ciprian gave is certainly an option but I feel it's limiting.
The solution below is much more flexible as you don't have to actually count anything and you can remove text from any position rather than just the end.

The following command (1 line) will remove any mention of .temp in all the files:

```
for filename in *; do mv "$filename" "${filename//.temp/}"; done
```

**Note** The "*" means all files in current folder. You can use *.temp to achieve exactly the same result as Ciprian's method. (that is, only removing .temp from files ending with .temp)

Comment: works fine. I was able to rename a bunch of files quickly. in a 1 liner !!

Comment: Glad I could help! I have used this command alot myself and always have gotten the results I was looking for :) 

Consider flagging my answer as "accepted", that way it will display at the top so other people can find the answer quicker.

Comment: for filename in $*;  do mv "$filename" "${filename//.temp/}"; This works fine. But this becomes tedious if I want to rename say 100 files and only of particular date. is there a way I pass only date with the script as a parameter and it renames files of that date only without having me to pass the filenames

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about UNIX, but since the question also have the Linux tag it may just be a UNIX/Linux confusion.

Most GNU/Linux distributions have a `rename` command.  Depending on the `rename` version, to replace `foo` with `bar` in `files` names the syntax may either be as simple as

```
rename foo bar files
```

or follow `sed`'s regexp syntax :

```
rename 's/foo/bar/' files
```

In your case, you want to replace `.temp` with an empty string (`''`) in all files ending with `.temp`, so depending on your `rename` version one of these commands should work :

```
rename .temp '' *.temp
```

or

```
rename 's/\.temp$//' *.temp
```

Answer (score -1):

Create the following script with a name like 'rename.sh':

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET_DIR=$1
TARGET_FILES="$TARGET_DIR/*.temp"

for fileName in $TARGET_FILES
do
    newFileName=${fileName::-5}
    mv -v "${fileName}" "${newFileName}"
done
```

**note** The `${var:offset:length}` expansion requires bash version 4 or higher.

Give it execution rights:

```
chmod a+x rename.sh
```

You need to call it and pass the name of the directory of the .temp files as a parameter. Call it like this:

```
./rename.sh /path/to/the/temp-files
```

The script loops over all the *.temp files in the target folder, extracts the last 5 chars from the file path ('.temp' is 5 chars) and moves the original file to the new file that doesn't contain .temp as the extension.

EDIT: tested on a CentOS 7

Comment: substring expression < 0 error

Comment: @Ritesh, I added verbose mode to the mv command. Please modify the script and run it again. Notice the -v option to the mv command. After that, please show the output. I'm suspecting a filename problem but we need to see exactly which is that.

Comment: Might have to do with ::- :)

Comment: @RickvanLieshout, ::-  works perfectly fine on a CentOS 7 where I tested.  ;-)

Comment: @CiprianStoica, ::- is a feature in bash version 4+, OP might be using a different bash version. Seeing as he/she didn't specify I think it's important to add this information to your post / provide a more version agnostic solution instead.

Comment: @CiprianStoica I modified and re ran. This is the error I get : ./rename.sh: line 8: -5: substring expression < 0

Comment: @CiprianStoica bash version is 4.1.2

Comment: @RickvanLieshout, you won! Your solution is indeed much more flexible than mine ( not to mention its readability). So, have a +1 from me. 
Thanks for suggesting that my post needs editing and improvement. You are definitely right, but I prefer will leave it exactly as it is (poor and inflexible) so the future generations to learn how NOT to answer a question on SO. 
Cheers ;-)