# How to rename a bunch of files

Tags: linux, rhel7

I have a bunch of files starting with "NCI_" How can I rename them to start with "NCIB_" instead of "NCI_"
I have tried using the below command in my folder containing the files:

```
rename 's/NCI_/NCIB_/' *
```

But it didn't work. Can anybody please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix Renaming Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688086/unix-renaming-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename multiple files based on pattern in Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1086502/608639), [Rename all files in a folder with a prefix in a single unix command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6329505/608639), [How to rename a certain prefix in multiple files?](https://askubuntu.com/q/878940), [Bulk rename, change prefix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47367), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the rename command as shown below:

```
rename NCI_ NCIB_ *
```

Check the screenshot for sample output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like

```
find . -name "NCI_*" -exec bash -c 'mv $0 ${0/NCI_/NCIB_}' {} \;
```

Find files and perform rename using `mv` by replacing the old string with the new one.

Answer (score -1):

There are two tools called `rename`, one from util-linux and another one written in Perl. The Perl version is sometimes available in package managers as `prename` or `perl-rename`.

Check `rename --help` to find out which one you have. The util-linux `rename` prints something like this:

```
$ rename --help

Usage:
 rename [options] <expression> <replacement> <file>...
...
```

The Perl `rename` prints something like this (it's known as `perl-rename` on my Arch Linux system):

```
$ perl-rename --help
Usage: perl-rename [OPTION]... PERLEXPR FILE...
Rename FILE(s) using PERLEXPR on each filename.
...
```

With Perl rename, depending on the name of its executable on your system, your command should work:

```
$ perl-rename 's/NCI_/NCIB_/' *
```

But if you have the util-linux version, then it should be something like this:

```
$ rename NCI_ NCIB_ *
```