# Bash - Rename Files recursively from Database Value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, recursion

I am quite new to the Linux.

I have a folder that has around 1000 files and that filenames stored under database.

What I want to do is rename all of them recursively with another value in the same database.

My DB Structure

```
oldVal      | newVal
oldFileName | newFileName
```

What is the shortest and the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance for the tips.

Comment: There are few  steps mentioned in a similar post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416990/shell-bash-shortcut-for-bulk-renaming-of-files-in-a-folder. I prefer the for loop as it gives me more control and uses in-built in bash (no extra installations / tools)

Comment: Recursively? Does your database contain the file names with path?

Comment: Or does *recursively* mean that the renamed file should maybe renamed again, for instance if the database contains the entries `name1 | name2` and `name2 | name3`, that *name1* should be renamed to *name3*?

Comment: What do you mean when you say **database**? Do you mean the files are in some database like MariaDB or postgres? Or, do you mean I have a text file I am using as a database?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, it does. [at]user1934428 It will just get renamed to name2. [at]David Mariadb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to export the database information to a text file? If yes, and for a MySQL database, you can try this.

First, execute this query in your MySQL...

```
SELECT field1,field2
FROM table
INTO OUTFILE '/your/path/with/files/to/rename/export.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

after, go to **/your/path/with/files/to/rename/** folder and paste this...

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
LIST=`cat /your/path/with/files/to/rename/export.txt`
for i in $LIST ;
do
 field1=`echo $i | cut -d',' -f1`
 field2=`echo $i | cut -d',' -f2`
 \mv "./"$field1 "./"$field2
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```